# Incremental Assignment

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I have been working with C++ for many years, but just realized something fishy about incremental assignment.

I have this snippet

```
  a = 4; 
  b = 2;
  c = 0;
  c = c + a > b; printf("a: %d\tb: %d\tc: %d\n",a,b,c);
  c = c + a > b; printf("a: %d\tb: %d\tc: %d\n",a,b,c);
  c +=    a < b; printf("a: %d\tb: %d\tc: %d\n",a,b,c);
  c +=    a > b; printf("a: %d\tb: %d\tc: %d\n",a,b,c);
  c +=    a > b; printf("a: %d\tb: %d\tc: %d\n",a,b,c);
```

And the result is

```
a: 4    b: 2    c: 1
a: 4    b: 2    c: 1
a: 4    b: 2    c: 1
a: 4    b: 2    c: 2
a: 4    b: 2    c: 3
```

If you note, the first two lines are the same. Or 'c' doesn't get updated after the first c = c + a > b;
However, the value of c gets updated when we use the incremental assignment +=

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you *imagine* should happen? Everything is exactly as it should be.

Comment: This falls under "ugly" code:  The '>` operator is not an arithmetic operator so it should NOT be used in an arithmetic statement or expression.  This was a hack from long ago when boolean types and operators were not available (in ancient languages).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<` has lower precedence than `+`.

`c = c + a > b;` is interpreted as `c = (c + a) > b;`

It is just so, there doesn't need to be a reason, but if there was one, it might be that people more often compare arithmetic expressions than use the results of comparisons in arithmetic expressions..

Answer (score 2):

In the first line, `c + a > b` is true, which converts to `1`, so the first line reads `c = 1;`. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler interprets your code as c = (c + a) > b where you probably want it to be interpreted as c = c + (a  > b).